# Should we consider also Yoga philosophy here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

My personal opinion is yes.

Yoga philosophy and buddhism are based on common roots and many concepts are very similar or exactly the same.

For example:

- Noble Eightfold Path are very similar to Yamas in Yoga
- Concept of Reincarnation
- Karma
- Meditation approach as technique to reach enlightenment
- Meditation positions: actually the lotus posture, usually used in Buddish for meditation, is a yoga asana
- Yantra
- Mudras

In general all philosophy born in the area between India/Nepal/Bhutan share the common base culture and so it is difficult to separate one from another.

For example, is this question in line with the scope:

- [Relationship between Buddhism, Hinduism and Yoga?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/123/relationship-between-buddhism-hinduism-and-yoga)

Comment: Note that the Hinduism.SE site should be launching later today. Some questions about yoga may also end up being on topic there.

Comment: I think Yoga can be considered in the middle of Hinduism and Buddhism and in someway Buddhism is a form of Yoga

Comment: Being based on common roots wouldn't be enough, IMO. You'd have to discuss yoga in a Buddhist context, i.e. Buddhist Yoga to allow it on this site; otherwise, where would we draw the line?

Comment: Is I think you are right because both are such huge argument but in the same time,IMO, it is good approach, not to be to strict in categorize things ... everything is linked at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would argue that yoga philosophy (and yoga more generally) in a Buddhist context is more than acceptable, but not yoga that is divorced from a Buddhist context. Those might be excellent questions, but they won't have much to do with the core of the site.

Comment: I think that "Buddhist context" makes all the difference. How many people who currently practice yoga also believe in not self, impermanence of all things, etc? The context has a huge effect on how you look at the world

Comment: Yoga teach not attachment

Answer (score 4):

I think Yoga (as Patanjali tradition) should **not** be discussed on Buddhist themed site. Only with *exception* of comparative buddhology. Then it should be welcome. Like if someone can explain **difference** of concept of *karma* between Buddhism and Yoga (or any other school).